# Use script variable inside textbox form

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to create a form which contains a message where I want to use some data imported from a CSV file.
The script will read the CSV rows and print a message that will contain data from it.

The issue is that the variables inside message textbox is not used instead a plain text is filled.
I think that this is related to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox but I can't figure it out
Any idea how I can resolve this?

Regards,
Adrian

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
 Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
    
 function show_menu {
     [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
     $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
     $form.Text = 'menu'
     $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(630,370)
     $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
     $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
     #$form.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::FromHandle((New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap -Argument $stream).GetHIcon())
        
     $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
     $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,295)
     $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
     $okButton.Text = 'OK'
     $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
     $okButton.Add_Click({ 
         $form.Tag = $textBox_recipient.Text;
         $form.Tag = $textBox_message.Text;
         $form.Close() 
         })
     $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
     $form.Controls.Add($okButton)
    
     $cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
     $cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(355,295)
     $cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
     $cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
     $cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
     $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
     $form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)
    
     $textBox_recipient = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
     $textBox_recipient.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,70)
     $textBox_recipient.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(245, 20)
     $textBox_recipient.ReadOnly = $true
     $form.Controls.Add($textBox_recipient)
 ##
     $textBox_recipient_select = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
     $textBox_recipient_select.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(460, 70)
     $textBox_recipient_select.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
     $textBox_recipient_select.Text = "Select CSV file"
     $textBox_recipient_select.add_Click({
             $ofd = New-Object system.windows.forms.Openfiledialog
             #$ofd.Filter = 'Supported file types (*.csv,*.xlsx)|*.csv,*.xlsx'
             $ofd.Filter = 'Supported file types (*.csv, *.xlsx)|*.csv; *.xlsx| All (*.*)|*.*'
             $script:recipient_filename = 'Not found'
             if ($ofd.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok')    {
                 $script:recipient_filename = $textbox_recipient.Text = $ofd.FileName
             }
         })
     #$textBox_recipient.Text = "C:\Users\Ady\Desktop\test.csv"
     $form.Controls.Add($textBox_recipient_select)
    
     $label_message = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
     $label_message.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,150)
     $label_message.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
     $label_message.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
     $label_message.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
     $label_message.Text = 'Message:'
     $form.Controls.Add($label_message)
    
     $textBox_message = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
     $textBox_message.Multiline = $True
     $textBox_message.Scrollbars = "Vertical"
     $textBox_message.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(210,150)
     $textBox_message.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 135)
     $textBox_message.Text = "Insert your text here. HTML format supported"
     $form.Controls.Add($textBox_message)
    
     $form.Topmost = $true
     $form.Add_Shown({ $textBox_recipient.Select(),$textBox_message.Select() })
     $result = $form.ShowDialog()
    
     if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
         $script:filename = "$(($textBox_recipient).Text)"
    
         $recipients = Import-csv -Path "$filename"
         $total_recipient_nr = get-content "$filename" | select-string "@" | measure-object -line
         $recipient_nr = 0
         foreach ($recipient in $recipients)    {
             if (++$recipient_nr % 31 -eq 0)
             {
                 Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
                 echo "waiting 1 minute"
             }
                    
             $script:user_email = $recipient.email
             $script:user_firstname = $recipient.firstname
             $script:user_lastname = $recipient.lastname
             $script:user_code = $recipient.code
             $script:message = $textBox_message.Text
             
                     Write-Host $message
         }
     }
 }
    
 show_menu
```

For example, the following csv:

```
firstname, lastname, email, code ---- header of csv file
firstname1, lastname1, email1@domain, code1
firstname2, lastname2, email2@domain, code2
```

What I want to do is to use variables like $user_email, $user_code inside "$textBox_message.Text" field of the form and for each line of the CSV file, the message to use the value of those variables. (recipient is a row from the csv file that contains different values at each foreach run)

```
$script:user_firstname = $recipient.firstname
$script:user_code = $recipient.code
$script:message = $textBox_message.Text
```

I run the script, the form appears and I replace the default text "Insert your text here. HTML format supported" of $textBox_message.Text with the following:
Hi $user_firstname. This is your code: $user_code

The result (value of $message var) by executing line 96, should be:
Hi firstname1. This is your code: code1 - at first run of foreach loop
and
Hi firstname2. This is your code: code2 - at second run of foreach loop

Instead, the result is:
Hi $user_firstname. This is your code: $user_code --- plain text (the value) of $message

Comment: where exactly you want to use a variable? can you please point that line out?

Comment: well not in the line but to use something lie $user_code in the textbox form
This var should be $script:message = $textBox_message.Text

So, if I fill the textbox with the following text "this is just a test message and firstname is $user_firstname, code is $user_code"

 Write-Host $message will show the plain text ""this is just a test message and firstname is $user_firstname, code is $user_code" instead of "this is just a test message and firstname is VALUE-OF-$user_firstname, code is VALUE-OF-$user_code"

Comment: Are you trying to get a input prompt ?

Comment: the input prompt (GUI form) it's working fine. the resulted text is plain text and doesn't take $var as variable, $ it's interpreted as a standard char

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful but have you reviewed.
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-form/

Comment: thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I edited the main post with more details

Answer (score 0):

This is from what I have observed from Powershell when trying to writing a simple string with variables:
if you use single quotes i.e.

```
$firstName = "John"
write-host 'First name is $firstName'
```

The output is going to be:

```
First name is $firstName
```

However if you use double quotes, you should get the variable value instead of variable being displayed as plain text. i.e.

```
$firstName = "John"
write-host "First name is $firstName" or  write-host "First name is $($firstName)"
```

you should get the desired output:

```
First name is John
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this but it's not the case here.
The ""issue" is caused by the messagebox.text witch generates a string

someone gsuggested solution: to use {0}, {1} … inside the textbox and make the message variable something like this:
$script:message = $script:message -f $recipient.firstname,$recipient.code

adding some keywords like user_firstname, to be used inside the textbox and replace them, will be easy for the person that will write the final message
$script:message = $script:message -replace 'user_firstname', '{0}' -replace 'user_code','{1}'